# Can command blocks detect punches with certain items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way for command blocks to detect when a certain item hits a mob? Like could I have a command block detect when I hit a mob with a stick and then use /execute to make it explode?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 1):

Put this command into a repeating command block and it will summon tnt that will instantly explode on every entity that gets hurt close to a player holding a stick.

```
execute at @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stick"}}] run execute at @e[distance=0.1..5,nbt={HurtTime:10s}] run summon tnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}
```

The command does NOT detect, HOW the entity got hurt, but it seems to often not work when the entity gets hurt by something other than a punch.